# Does Haskell have some sort of number conversion to scientific format?

Tags: haskell, math, exponential

In JS we have `Number.toExponential()` which converts converts a number into its scientific notation (i.e : for `1000 -> "1e3"`).

I checked on hoggle but I can't seem to find it.

Note : toExponential changes `num -> string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf)  and work with a `%e` or `%E` specifier:

```
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%e" 14.25 :: String
"1.425e1"
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%E" 14.25 :: String
"1.425E1"
```

here `%e` specifies the scientific notation with a lowercase `e`, and the `%E` with an uppercase `E`. The output type of `printf` can be a `String`, or an `IO ()`. If the `String` type is used we get a `String` with the formatted type, for `IO ()` it will print the type to the stdout.

---

[@Noughtmare also mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149481/does-haskell-have-some-sort-of-number-conversion-to-scientific-format#comment122216985_69149563) the [**`showEFloat :: RealFloat a => Maybe Int -> a -> String -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showEFloat) to prepend a string with the exponential representation of a [**`RealFloat`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFloat) number type.

---

You can also work with a `Scientific` number, and then work with [**`formatScientific :: FPFormat -> Maybe Int  -> Scientific -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.7.0/docs/Data-Scientific.html#v:formatScientific).

If you thus install the [**`scientific`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific), we can implement this with:

```
Prelude> import Data.Scientific
Prelude Data.Scientific> formatScientific Exponent Nothing 1000
"1.0e3"
```

This thus means that the `1000` type should be `Scientific` not a `

Comment: Maybe it is also good to mention [`Numeric.showEFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showEFloat) (I personally don't like the magic of `printf`).